# nendの広告を貼り付けると画面がフリーズしてしまう

Tags: android, monaca, nend

現在、nendの広告を貼り付けるとデバッカー、ビルドともに画面がフリーズしてしまう現象が起きています

前までは普通にできていたのですが、２月の前半にmonacaがアップデートしたあたりからこのような現象が起きています。

今まで正常に動作していて、特に何も触れていないアプリまでも、デバッカーで確認するとエラー表示がでてきます。nendの広告を外すと正常に動作します。

ちなみに、レクタングル広告は正常に動作するのですが、その他、アイコン広告などがエラーがでるようです。

何か解決策などありましたら、ご教授おねがいいたします